# How to specify input file format when loading data into Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to load data from Gzip archive into Hive table but my gzip files have extension like for example:

apache_log.gz_localhost

When I specify HDFS directory location where these files are located Hive doesn't recognize GZip compressed files because it is searching for files with .gz extension.

Is it possible to define file type when loading data into Hive? Something like (PSEUDO):

> **set input.format=gzip;**
>
> LOAD DATA INPATH /tmp/logs/ INTO TABLE apache_logs;

Here is my SQL for table creation:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE access_logs (
`ip`                STRING,
`time_local`        STRING,
`method`            STRING,
`request_uri`       STRING,
`protocol`          STRING,
`status`            STRING,
`bytes_sent`        STRING,
`referer`           STRING,
`useragent`         STRING,
`bytes_received`    STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'input.regex'='^(\\S+) \\S+ \\S+ \\[([^\\[]+)\\] "(\\w+) (\\S+) (\\S+)" (\\d+) (\\d+|\-) "([^"]+)" "([^"]+)".* (\\d+)'
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/tmp/logs/';
```

Comment: `set mapred.map.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GZipCodec;` at beginning of script

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help.

Thank You

Comment: Interesting question, hope it gets more attention.

Answer (score 7):

Why not change file name to `xxx.gz` after put in HDFS?

If you really wanna support `.gz_localhost`, I think you can custom your own `GzipCodec` to relize it:

1. Create a your own `NewGzipCodec` Class which extend `GzipCodec`:

   public class NewGzipCodec extends org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec {
      }
2. override method `getDefaultExtension`:

   public String getDefaultExtension() { return ".gz_locahost"; }
3. javac and compress `NewGzipCodec.class` to `NewGzipCodec.jar`
4. upload `NewGzipCodec.jar` to `{$HADOOP_HOME}/lib`
5. set up your `core-site.xml`

> ```
> <property>
>   <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
>   <value>NewGzipCodec, org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec</value>
> </property>
> ```

Comment: This is an interesting idea and shed some light on how codec's implemented and how they could be extended.